# Elastic search error operation [search] and lang [groovy] is disabled?

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 1.7.1 and when i am trying to use script_score or script_fields it is showing the error ScriptException[scripts of type inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] is disabled can anyone please tell me how can i remove this error. my code is given below

```
function_score: {
        query: {
          query_string: {
            query: shop_search,
            fields: [ 'shop_name']
          } 
        },    
        functions: [
          {
            script_score: {
              script: "_score * doc['location'].value"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add `script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on` to `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart the node.

Comment: but i have to add this line where inside my yml file inside my yml file every line starts with either # or ## dont know where to put it ??

Comment: Just add it as a new line, it doesn't matter where in the file.

Comment: For those who got this error while aggregating/grouping and Googled their way here: `script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on`

Answer (score 14):

adding `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true` to .yml works for me

For ES Version 2.x+

```
script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
```

Answer (score 7):

Add 

`script.engine.groovy.inline.aggs: on
script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on`
 
to elasticsearch.yml
and restart

Answer (score 0):

For those with ES 2.x+

`script.inline: true
script.indexed: true`

**Make sure you prefix the lines with a space!**